# setting custom arguments in vimrc

Tags: linux, vim

I've tried looking everywhere for information on this but have come up short. I want to be able to  use vimrc to set my own arguments for opening  vim with. The idea being that if I run "vim -#code foo.bar" then the vimrc file will set syntax highlighting and line numbers but if run "vim foo.bar" then the file will open without line numbers or syntax highlighting. This seems like an obvious thing to want to do and I'm sure I've missed a trick somewhere but I'm struggling to get vim to play nicely. It seems silly to have to set a bash alias for this when the vimrc file is designed for this kind of thing.

My vimrc currently looks like this:

```
if $ARGV[0] == "#code"
set nu
filetype plugin on
syntax on
endif
```

Comment: The vimrc file is not designed for this kind of thing. And where did you get `$ARGV[0]` from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a workaround for similar situation
I have special vimrc (.coding_vimrc)
wich loads usual vimrc inside

```
source .vimrc
```

and contains all special settings for coding

Run vim with

```
vim -u .coding_vimrc foo.bar
```

PS:
assumes full path in both cases

Comment: Thank you!

I was beginning to think I was mad to try this. This is a great work around that gives me exactly what I'm looking for. Really helpful.